# Как работает в Entity Framework навигационные свойства с коллекцией?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Допустим у нас есть классы

```
public class Forest {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TreeType> TreeTypes { get; set; } = new List<TreeType>();
}

public class TreeType {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual SomeLinkedData SomeLinkedData { get; set; }

    public int ForestId { get; set; }
    public virtual Forest Forest { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext 
{
    public DbSet<TreeType> TreeTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Forest> Forests { get; set; }
}
```

И мне нужно оптимизировать запрос.
Я могу сделать так
`db.TreeTypes.Where(x=>x.Forest.Id == forest.Id).Count()`
в этом запросе у меня всего один запрос к базе данных и он сразу возвратит число

А могу сделать так
`forest.TreeTypes.Count()`

И я не могу понять как он будет работать во втором случае, будет ли он получать сначала все типы деревьев а потом вычислит их количество, в результате в отличае от первого запроса нагрузка на базу будет больше и будет в процессе работы обработаны данные которые можно вообще не обрабатывать.
Либо и во втором случае он тоже оптимизирует запрос.
Как я понимаю оптимизации во втором случае не будет.
И если её не будет, то почему, это же столько лишних рессурсов тратить.

И в продолжении вопроса. Я могу сделать `db.Forests.Include("TreeTypes.SomeLinkedData")`
а как такое можно сделать через
`forest.TreeTypes` тут нету такой функции Include
получается какой-то урезанный функционал у навигационных свойств.

На данный момент я все такие запросы делаю через `db.` но это не особенно удобно, да и объект `db` не в любом контексте доступен, приходится его прокидывать, что тоже мне не особенно нравится, когда можно было бы просто к навигационному свойству объекта обратиться.

Comment: `public virtual ICollection<TreeType> { get; set; } = new List<TreeType>();` а разве ту не должно быть имя свойства?

Comment: @Bald да, извиняюсь)), поправляю

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вызов `forest.TreeTypes.Count()` состоит и двух частей. Сначала вызывается `forest.TreeTypes` - и в этот момент (если включен LazyLoading) из БД подгружаются все связанные записи. К моменту загрузки данных из БД библиотека EF еще не знает, что вам нужен лишь `Count()`. Вы совершенно правильно сделали, сочтя такой код подозрительным.

Определить, будет ли запрос выполняться на стороне БД или на стороне приложения - обычно очень просто. На стороне БД будут выполнены запросы к коллекциям, сделанные через интерфейс `IQueryable<>`. `DbSet` этот интерфейс реализует, а `ICollection<>` его не содержит.

---

В EF есть особый синтаксис для превращения навигационных свойств в запросы. Возможно, вам следует воспользоваться им:

```
db.Entry(forest).Collection(f => f.TreeTypes).Query().Count();
```

Загрузить `SomeLinkedData` одновременно с `TreeTypes` также довольно просто:

```
db.Entry(forest).Collection(f => f.TreeTypes).Query().Include("SomeLinkedData").Load();
foreach (var tt in forest.TreeTypes) { 
    // Этот цикл больше не вызовет загрузки коллекции - она уже загружена
    Console.WriteLine(tt.SomeLinkedData.Foo); // И SomeLinkedData уже загружены тоже
}
```

Comment: Я так и думал, спасибо что разъяснили мои сомнения на этот счёт. Единственное что мне тут кажется не логчиным, что никак нельзя из самого объекта получить экземпляр текущей `db`, придётся его каждый раз прокидывать. Но по-идее в прокси `forest.TreeTypes` где-то уже содержится информация про `db` жаль что нету синтаксиса для её извлечения.

Answer (score -1):

1. При разрабатывании кода с исползованием библиотеки EF нужно понимать, что большая часть LINQ-функций фактически не вызывается, в место этого EF строит дерево выражений, которое используется для динамического формирования SQL запроса. Поэтому `db.TreeTypes.Where(x=>x.Forest.Id == forest.Id).Count()` и `forest.TreeTypes.Count()` теоретически должны привести к формированию идентичных SQL-запросов к БД. Какие фактические запросы будут отправлены серверу БД можно посмотреть воспользовавшись утилитой SQL Server Profiler, которую можно найти, например, в составе дистирутива MS SQL Server Developer Edition.
2. Метод `Include` определен только для типа `DbSet<>`, и не может быть вызван для простой коллекции. И еще момент, `Include` это некая директива, которая иснтуктирует EF о том что необходимо постоить такой SQL-запрос, который загрузит дополнительные связанные сущности. И все это может произойти только в рамках этого первичного запроса. ЕА не умеет динамически подгружать данные по связанным сущностям после того как уже эти сущности выбраны из БД.

Comment: `db.TreeTypes.Where(x=>x.Forest.Id == forest.Id).Count()` и `forest.TreeTypes.Count()` не должны формировать идентичные запросы ни в теории, ни на практике!

Comment: Да, прошу прощения, как правильно заметил Павел, действительно при вызове `forest.TreeTypes.Count()` будет вызван метод `IEnumerable<T>.Count()` поскольку `forest.TreeTypes` имеет тип `ICollection<>` к которому уже применяется метод IEnumerable<T>.Count()